# CSS Grid Spacing

Tags: css, css-grid

I have 3 rows and each row will be split into two part (`Text` & `Link`). Right now they're split 50% & 50%. What I'd like is for the link to come directly after the `@ symbol` but some `Text` could be longer than another. Is there a way to make *all* the text width the width of the longest `Text` item? I don't really care if the shorter Text will have space between its `@ symbol` and its `Link`. I'm trying to avoid writing a specific pixel width. I'd like to use Grid to make it dynamic based on the longest `Text` and line up the `Links`.
[image]

```markdown
Text         @ Link
Long Text    @ Link
Longest Text @ Link
Text         @ Link

vs.

Text  @ Link
Long Text @ Link
Longest Text  @ Link
Text @ Link
```

**MY CODE**

```css
.parentDiv {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3;
}
.parentDiv .row {
  grid-template-areas: "a b";
  display: grid;
}
.row p {
  grid-area: "a";
  text-align: left;
  width: max-content;
}

.row a {
  grid-area: "b";
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div className="parentDiv">
  <div className="row">
    <p>Title @</p>
    <a href="https://example.com/"> Link </a>
  </div>
  <div className="row">
    <p>Longer Title @</p>
    <a href="https://example.com/"> Link </a>
  </div>
  <div className="row">
    <p>Longest Title @</p>
    <a href="https://example.com/"> Link </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: okay, if i ditched the rows, how do i make the `<p>` width for all of them be the width of the _**longest**_ one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you need to lose the `row` wrappers...or just use a table or at least CSS-Tables

```css
.parentDiv {
  display: table;
}

.parentDiv .row {
  display: table-row;
}

.row p {
  display: table-cell;
}

.row a {
  display: table-cell
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div class="row">
    <p>Title @</p>
    <a href="https://example.com/"> Link </a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Longer Title @</p>
    <a href="https://example.com/"> Link </a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Longest Title @</p>
    <a href="https://example.com/"> Link </a>
  </div>
</div>
```